# JQuery custom events 'on' non-document element when not triggered from a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, model-view

I can't seem to get JQuery custom events to work as advertised when the trigger is *not* bound to a specific DOM element. I am trying to understand how to implement a model-view-controller pattern in which the model has absolutely no DOM-related code, yet triggers custom events for the view.

The model's setValue() method trigger's a custom 'ValueChanged' event using '$.event.trigger'.

In the view, 'on' is used to bind both a 'keyup' and the custom 'ValueChanged' event to an input element. The keyup handler calls the model's setValue() method, but the input element's ValueChanged handler never gets called.

I can bind the document to handle the ValueChanged, but that handler has no reference to the input -- it also gets called twice. I would really like the input element's handler to be called so I get a reference to the input element.

In the code example I show two Views that get created by the $(document).ready function, but ideally I would like to be able to generate additional views programmatically (this is just an example of the problem).

More than likely the problem is with my misunderstanding of some crucial concept.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
function Model (value){
    this.value = value;
}
Model.prototype.setValue = function (value){
    console.log('Model.setValue: ', value);
    oldValue = this.value;
    this.value = value;
    $.event.trigger({
        type: 'ValueChanged',
        oldValue: oldValue,
        newValue: this.value
    });
}
Model.prototype.getValue = function (){
    return this.value;
}

function View (container, model){
    if(typeof container == 'string')
        this.container = document.getElementById(container);
    else
        this.container = container;
    this.input = document.createElement('input');
    this.input.model = model;
    this.container.appendChild(this.input);
    this.span = document.createElement('span');
    $(this.span).text('initial value');
    this.container.appendChild(this.span);
    // set the input component to show the number
    $(this.input).val(this.input.model.getValue());
    ref = this;

    // this one gets called twice
    $(document).on('ValueChanged', function (e){
        console.log('ValueChanged (document): ' + e.newValue + ' ' + e.target);
    });

    // this one never gets called
    $(this.input).on('ValueChanged', function (e){
        console.log('ValueChanged (input): ' + e.newValue);
        // set the input component to show the number
        $(ref.span).text(e.newValue);
    });

    $(this.input).on('keyup', function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13) {
            //set the new value in the model; 'this' is the input component that got the keyup event
            this.model.setValue(this.value);
            //e.preventDefault();
        }
    });     
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    view1 = new View('container1', new Model(1));
    view2 = new View('container2', new Model(2));
    console.log('view1.input.model.value: ' + view1.input.model.getValue() + ',     view2.input.model.value: ' + view2.input.model.getValue());
    console.log('view1.input.value: ' + view1.input.value + ', view2.input.value: ' + view2.input.value);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='container1'>
</div>
<div id='container2'>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have arrived at a solution with the correct behavior, shown below, but it requires the Model to keep an array of the Views (and also each View must call the model's attachView() method :(

This version also shows multiple views for the same model, which is an important feature of model-view-controller.

Is there any way to achieve the same result but without the Model needing *any* information about the Views?

Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>

function Model (value){
    this.value = value;
    this.views = [];
}
Model.prototype.attachView = function (view){
    this.views.push(view);
}
Model.prototype.setValue = function (value){
    console.log('Model.setValue: ', value);
    oldValue = this.value;
    this.value = value;
    for(var i = 0; i < this.views.length; i++){
    $(this.views[i]).trigger({
        type: 'ValueChanged',
        oldValue: oldValue,
        newValue: this.value
        });
    }
}
Model.prototype.getValue = function (){
    return this.value;
}

function View (container, model){
    this.container = document.getElementById(container);
    this.input = document.createElement('input');
    this.input.model = model;
    model.attachView(this);
    this.container.appendChild(this.input);
    this.span = document.createElement('span');
    $(this.span).text('initial value');
    this.container.appendChild(this.span);
    // set the input component to show the model's number
    $(this.input).val(this.input.model.getValue());

    $(this).on('ValueChanged', function (e){
        console.log('ValueChanged: ' + e.newValue);
        // set the span to show the number
        $(this.span).text(e.newValue);
    });

    $(this.input).on('keyup', function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13) {
            //set the new value in the model; 'this' is the input component that got the keyup event
            this.model.setValue(this.value);
        }
    });     
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    view1 = new View('container1', new Model(1));
    var model2 = new Model(2);
    view2 = new View('container2', model2);
    view3 = new View('container3', model2);
    console.log('view1.input.model.value: ' + view1.input.model.getValue() + ', view2.input.model.value: ' + view2.input.model.getValue());
    console.log('view1.input.value: ' + view1.input.value + ', view2.input.value: ' +         view2.input.value);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='container1' />
<div id='container2' />
<div id='container3' />
</body>
</html>
```